# typescript: Incorrect return type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I've created a function, that takes values of certain type and filters them. Here it is:

```js
import {isMatch} from 'lodash';

export function predicate<T>(compareWith: Partial<T>): OperatorFunction<T[], T[]> {
    return src$ => src$.pipe(map(value => {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            return value.filter(element => isMatch(element as any, compareWith));
        }
        throw new Error('Value is not an array');
    }));
}
```

Now when I'm using it on the array of `Customer` type model like `predicate({CustomerId: 100})` (`CustomerId` is a property of `Customer` model), I have this error:

`Type 'Observable<{ CustomerId: Number; }[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Customer[]>'.`

However, if I explicitly call it as `predicate<Customer>({CustomerId: 100})`, it will work fine.

How can I configure the types properly to have a Customer as a returned type?

Here's a function where it fails:

```js
getCustomers(customerId) {
   return method$<Customer[]>.pipe(predicate({CustomerId: customerid}));
}
```

Update:

Here's a small workaround, that works. But I don't like it:

```js
export function predicate<T, P extends T>(compareWith: Partial<P>): OperatorFunction<T[]> {
    return src$ => src$.pipe(map(value => {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            return value.filter(element => isMatch(element as any, compareWith));
        }
        throw new Error('Value is not an array');
    }));
}
```

Comment: It's saying that `{CustomerId: customerid}` is not a complete Customer - you will need to typecast it to force it to conform or create a complete customer type.

Comment: @fredrik I understand this. The question is how can I avoid explicit typing there. That operator will be used a lot and I don't want to explicitly set model there everywhere

Comment: You can't avoid it as far as I know. If you want it typed you have to live with the consequences all the way.

Comment: Your 'workaround' is the way to go, IMO. The problem with the original signature is that, IIRC, inference starts with the parameters, so `T` is inferred to be `{ CustomerId: Number; }`. Your 'workaround' - I wouldn't call it that - doesn't include `T` in the parameters, so it infers `T` from the return type. Maybe that will help you like it a little more? I think it's fine.